# How do you programatically add a booking item to the cart?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to add a bookable product to the cart programatically, with a date set so the slot is reserved — just as if the user used the booking calendar on the single product page.

I have been able to achieve the functionality with the solution proposed here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741066/how-to-add-a-bookable-product-to-woocommerce-cart-programmatically] with having a form that submits to the same page but this is not an ideal solution.

I have searched through the plugin files to find out how the booking calendar adds the cart item but cannot work out how.

It does not work by doing `WC()->cart->add_to_cart($id)` sadly.

This is using WooCommerce with the WooCommerce Bookings plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct method

```
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart($id);
```

Comment: I meant to do that, have edited my question. This is not working for me with a bookable product.